# Swift, iOS: How to convert a string containing number and character (i.e ',' or ',') into number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have an double that i am converting using `NSMassFormatter` from kg to lb.

```
let massFormatter = NSMassFormatter() 
var xyz = massFormatter.stringFromKilograms(10000.000)
// xyz "22,046.226 lb"
```

Now I want a way to extract the number from the string. Also if I change the Locale to say `es` (Spain) then the value becomes `"10.000,000 kg"` (It actually returns `"10.000 kg"`, removing the decimal points for unknown reasons), but i want a way such that I can extract the number regardless of the locale. Is there any standard way? Like use a **regrex** or some function in `NSNumberFormatter`?
Thank you

Comment: "(It actually returns "10.000 kg", removing the decimal points for unknown reasons)" Wouldn't that just be because the standard Spanish locale's numbers are written like "1.234.567,89"? Are these numbers going to be input and read by users who are in the locale of the phone? If they are, you should be using that locale.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that fully independent of locale. The main problem is that identical string will be interpreted differently depending on what locale it is run against.

Best solution will be to identify all the possible formats, define all possible formatters and try to get `numberFromString:` from each formatter - until the first one to obtain the correct result.

The other solution, if you're getting the data from user input, is to explain the correct format to users and provide them with instant validation - i.e. showing "incorrect format" error message. Some apps have used the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` keyboard to restrict user, so that you'll have only numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Two keys to the problem, finding the localized units (the "kg") part in your example, and converting the string using localized grouping and decimal separators:

```
// convert mass to string
var lbs = massFormatter.stringFromKilograms(10000)
println("\(lbs)")

// get localized unit specifier and remove from formatted string
var units = massFormatter.unitStringFromKilograms(10000, usedUnit: nil)
if let range = lbs.rangeOfString(units) {
    lbs.replaceRange(range, with: "")
}

// get number formatter and set it to use grouping separator (, or .)
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

// get number back
var kg = numberFormatter.numberFromString(lbs)
println("\(kg)")
```